# How to create a Comma-separated list of label IDs from a API response based on a predefined array of values in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I obtain the following response from an API call:

```
[
  {
    "id": "64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbea4",
    "idBoard": "64d74180af9431c1b1dccc54",
    "name": "News",
    "color": "blue",
    "uses": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbe9b",
    "idBoard": "64d74180af9431c1b1dccc54",
    "name": "Addition",
    "color": "green",
    "uses": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbea5",
    "idBoard": "64d74180af9431c1b1dccc54",
    "name": "Deprecation",
    "color": "orange",
    "uses": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbead",
    "idBoard": "64d74180af9431c1b1dccc54",
    "name": "Power-Ups",
    "color": "purple",
    "uses": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbeac",
    "idBoard": "64d74180af9431c1b1dccc54",
    "name": "Deletion",
    "color": "red",
    "uses": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbea3",
    "idBoard": "64d74180af9431c1b1dccc54",
    "name": "Update",
    "color": "yellow",
    "uses": 0
  }
]
```

and I have defined an array of names:

`let listOfValues = ["News", "Addition", "Deprecation", "Power-Ups"]`

I know have to generate a Comma-separated list of all the label IDs that corresponds to the name defined in the listOfValues.

Can somebody help me here please on how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Sure, I can help you with that. You can achieve this in TypeScript by iterating through the API response and checking if the `name` value matches any of the names in your `listOfValues` array. If there is a match, you can push the corresponding `id` into a new array. Finally, you can join the id values with commas to create a comma-separated list. Here's how you can do it:

```
const apiResponse = [
  {
    "id": "64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbea4",
    "idBoard": "64d74180af9431c1b1dccc54",
    "name": "News",
    "color": "blue",
    "uses": 0
  },
  // ... other items ...
];

const listOfValues = ["News", "Addition", "Deprecation", "Power-Ups"];

// Filter the API response based on the names in the listOfValues array
const filteredLabels = apiResponse.filter(label => listOfValues.includes(label.name));

// Extract the IDs from the filtered labels
const labelIds = filteredLabels.map(label => label.id);

// Create a comma-separated list of label IDs
const commaSeparatedIds = labelIds.join(',');

console.log(commaSeparatedIds); // Outputs: "64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbea4,64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbe9b,64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbea5,64d7418053ef33a7bdfbbead"
```

In this example, `filteredLabels` will contain the label objects that match the names in the `listOfValues` array. Then, we extract the `id` values from these labels using the `map` function, and finally, we join the id values using the join function to create a comma-separated list.